# Creating lists within a list properly

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a List that hold a collection of lists that get generated from an SQLite table but I'm having trouble getting things to work. The current iteration that I've tried is this. What is the correct way to populate a master list with a collection of lists and then cycle through lists?

```
// Single Drift list
public static List<Drift> Drift = new List<Drift>();

// List of all available drifts
public static List<List<Drift>> Drifts = new List<List<Drift>>();


public void UpdateListData(string driftID)
    {
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM \"" + driftID + "\" ";
        GameManager.Drifts.Add(dbManager.Query<Drift>(sql));

        foreach (List<Drift> drift in GameManager.Drifts)
        {
            Debug.Log("is in the Drifts list");
        }
    }
```

But it's giving me the error:

```
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Argument is out of range.
Parameter name: index
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Drift].get_Item (Int32 index) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/List.cs:633)
DriftManager.GetDriftStep (Int32 currentStep) (at Assets/_Scripts/DriftManager.cs:26)
DriftManager.DisplayDriftStep (Int32 step) (at Assets/_Scripts/DriftManager.cs:98)
EventManager.GetDriftStep (Int32 step) (at Assets/_Scripts/EventManager.cs:43)
DriftManager.CheckDriftProgress () (at Assets/_Scripts/DriftManager.cs:77)
DriftManager.InitDrift (Int32 driftNumSteps, System.String driftName) (at Assets/_Scripts/DriftManager.cs:67)
EventManager.GenerateNewDrift (Int32 steps, System.String title) (at Assets/_Scripts/EventManager.cs:14)
GameManager.<Start>m__0 () (at Assets/_Scripts/GameManager.cs:61)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:165)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent_0.cs:58)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.Press () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:36)
UnityEngine.UI.Button.OnPointerClick (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData eventData) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/UI/Core/Button.cs:45)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute (IPointerClickHandler handler, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:50)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[IPointerClickHandler] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventFunction`1 functor) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Extensions/guisystem/UnityEngine.UI/EventSystem/ExecuteEvents.cs:261)
```

Comment: Which line has the exception? You're not doing any list lookups (besides `.Query<>()`).

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bu0xKs)?  Just wrote this really quick  to try and gather an idea of what you're expecting.

Comment: Your code allows a SQL Injection Attack.  Please fix.

Comment: Your error is occuring in `DriftManager.GetDriftStep` (DriftManager line 26) which was not included in your question. The `UpdateListData` you included is not involved in the error at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this depending on what you need to do with each item.

```
foreach (var drift in GameManager.Drifts)
{
    foreach(var item in drift)
    {
        //do something with the item
    }    
}
```

This should properly iterate over every item in that Drifts collection with the nested list.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a little trouble fully understanding what you're trying to accomplish, but I assume you want to retrieve each object that is within each list inside the main list.

When dealing with a list that is composed of other lists, `var lstOfLsts = new List<List<object>>();`, I would highly suggest using [`.SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336(v=vs.110).aspx).

I have created an [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bu0xKs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var lstIntOne = new List<int>() {1,2,3};
        var lstIntTwo = new List<int>() {4,5,6};
        var lstIntThree = new List<int>() {7,8,9};

        var lstOfLstInts = new List<List<int>>();

        lstOfLstInts.Add(lstIntOne);
        lstOfLstInts.Add(lstIntTwo);
        lstOfLstInts.Add(lstIntThree);

        var lstAllNumbers = lstOfLstInts.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();

        foreach(var item in lstAllNumbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);    
        }
    }
}

// Output
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
// 5
// 6
// 7
// 8
// 9
```

So, I have 3 lists of numbers and I want to put each of those lists into one main list.  Then I want to iterate through the big list, and retrieve each number, which is where the `.SelectMany` comes into play.

Let me know this helps.